# proguard error when i export application

Tags: android, proguard

```
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced method 'void onSetLayoutParams(android.view.View,android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' in class android.support.v7.widget.ViewGroup
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced method 'void onViewAdded(android.view.View)' in class android.support.v7.widget.ViewGroup
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced method 'void onViewRemoved(android.view.View)' in class android.support.v7.widget.ViewGroup
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced method 'void onChildVisibilityChanged(android.view.View,int,int)' in class android.support.v7.widget.ViewGroup
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced field 'int mPaddingLeft' in class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced field 'int mPaddingRight' in class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced field 'int mPaddingTop' in class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout: can't find referenced field 'int mPaddingBottom' in class android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] Warning: there were 8 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-03-06 16:35:09 - mathsMagic]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your Proguard configuration file:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

If that didn't work, try this:

```
-dontwarn  android.support.v7.widget.**
```

Comment: my apk is now giving crashes

Comment: Install the exported apk file on the emulator and see what it says in logcat

Comment: of course its failing, if you tell it to ignore an error during compilation that error isnt going to go away